# How many military coups was the USA involved in continental America?

Tags: united-states, south-america

Chomsky recently pointed out that the mass migration seen on our TVs from Central America has its roots in USA meddling in the governance of countries south of its border. For [example](https://nacla.org/blog/2012/12/13/interview-noam-chomsky-latin-america) the military coup in Honduras in 2009 overthrowing the government of Manuel Zelayo and Haiti in 2004 and 2010.

Q. Over the last century, that is from 1917-2017 how many governments have been overthrown south of its border with either the direct or indirect help of the USA.

Q. Has the USA ever attempted to meddle in the internal affairs of the country North of its border -Canada?

Comment: Is anything missing from the Wikipedia article [United States involvement in regime change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_involvement_in_regime_change)?

Comment: @semipaiscuba: Yeah, whether it meddled with Canada ;).  Anyway from that comprehensive list fifteen governments. That's quite a list.

Comment: @semipaiscuba: Anyway, I forgot to thank you for finding me that list. Thanks.

Comment: @semipasicuba: I realise that this has nothing to do with history but can you tell me why none of this is mentioned by the main news channels when they are relating the havoc that goes in South America?

Comment: You'd have to ask the news media. Also, if you actually want answers to your comments, it would help if you spell people's usernames correctly. Just type the @ symbol and the first letter of the name and you can select it from there.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Hmm, nothing about keeping people in the dark. Or have I too suspicious a mind?

Comment: "_Keeping people in the dark_"?  Really?  It's on Wikipedia!

Comment: @semipaiscuba: Yeah, *now*. But TV has a long history when such resources weren't so easily available. They had a reach of tens of millions and they barely informed them. They mostly kept them amused. They still are. The history of TV lies in the entertainment industry, whereas wikipedia lies in the history of scholarship. The different provenance of the two explains the difference.

Comment: Anyway, if you're happy that article answers your question, do you want to close it or would you prefer me to do it?

Comment: @semipasicuba: Why should you want to close it because I've found some useful information? Do you do that with other questions?

Comment: Only the ones that are off-topic. From the close reasons: "***it can be definitively answered by a single link to the relevant topic on Wikipedia or another standard reference source***".

Comment: @sempaiscuba: First you ask my permission to close the question and then you put it on hold. Why bother asking?

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Anyway, you've not answered my second question. Has the US ever meddled in the affairs of Canada?

Comment: Because - as I explained above - it appears to be off topic for this site.  This is explained in more detail in the [Help centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @Sempsiscuba: I disagree: It's **not** off-topic, because in that case you wouldn't have bothered to find a resource that answers the question.

Comment: I simply typed your question into Google.  It's the 3rd page listed.